# What kind of illness was Kaori Miyazono suffering from?

Tags: your-lie-in-april

Does anyone know what kind of illness Kaori Miyazono was suffering from?

- Kaori Miyazono is a girl about 14 years old
- It has caused her to be hospitalized several times prior to the events of the series.
- The disease causes her to collapse during a violin performance
- It appears to cause her to have trouble walking, and is ameliorated by rehabilitation
- It causes seizures that can cause unconsciousness, and lead to her being placed in the ICU
- It is cured or temporarily halted by surgery, but the surgery is highly risky, and can result in patient death

According to the [series' wiki](http://shigatsu-wa-kimi-no-uso.wikia.com/wiki/Kaori_Miyazono), it is speculated that it was [bone marrow failure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_marrow_failure),

> due to the change in her skin pigmentation and the need for an operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my theory, her disease is Friedreich's Ataxia. Symptons begins between the ages of 5 to 15. Muscle weakness in the arms and legs and loss of coordination are symptons.

It causes heart disorders. In Episode 20, she may be having a severe and painful tachycardia, and a following cardiac arrest. The surgery may be to implant a pacemaker, but another arrest killed her during the surgery.

Answer (score 3):

My hypothesis is that she is suffering from advanced multiple sclerosis. The extreme exhaustion along with the loss of motor function in her legs (Episode 15-Liar) and hands (Episode 21- Snow) are her most obvious symptoms.  However, the risky operation she undergoes is the only thing that make me question my theory.

Comment: Do you possibly have any sources for this answer?